# Android user location separating class

Tags: java, android

this app gets user location and displays longitude and latitude it was working good when it was all in main activity I tried to separate it in another class and call it in main activity but it didn't work and I am getting null values

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private TextView textView;
    private Double longitude, latitude;
    private GetLocation getLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        getLocation=new GetLocation();
        longitude=getLocation.getLongitude();
        latitude=getLocation.getLatitude();
        textView.setText(longitude+"\n"+latitude);
    }
}
```

**GetLocation**

```
public class GetLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Double latitude,longitude;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        locationRequest=new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        googleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(GetLocation.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(GetLocation.this,
                            "permission was granted, :)",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try{
                        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                                googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
                    }catch(SecurityException e){
                        Toast.makeText(GetLocation.this,
                                "SecurityException:\n" + e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(GetLocation.this,
                            "permission denied, ...:(",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(GetLocation.this,
                "onConnectionFailed: \n" + connectionResult.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location!=null){
            latitude=location.getLatitude();
            longitude=location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    public Double getLatitude(){return latitude;}
    public Double getLongitude(){return longitude;}
}
```

Comment: I believe the activity is not started when you call new GetLocation() as it's a AppCompatActivity and so you are getting null for location coordinates. You may want to start the activity using a Intent .

Comment: what to edit if I want to use the class without leaving main activity?

Comment: Try this -
Intent intent=new Intent(GetLocation.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);